# PHP: How to display child node defined in XML xpath?

Tags: php, xml

Hi I want to find a xml node with a text string "CAT1" and display but I seems to not able to get it right.  Can someone advise me what's wrong.

---catalog.xml---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Catalog>
    <Category>
        <Name>CAT1</Name>
        <Location>
            <Room> Alpha </Room>
        </Location>  
    </Category>
    <Category>
        <Name>CAT2</Name>
        <Location>
            <Room> Bravo </Room>
        </Location>  
    </Category>
    <Category>
        <Name>CAT3</Name>
        <Location>
            <Room> Charlie </Room>
        </Location>  
    </Category>
    <Category>
        <Name>CAT4</Name>
        <Location>
            <Room> Delta </Room>
        </Location>  
    </Category>
</Catalog>
```

---arr0.php---

```
<?php
$catalog = simplexml_load_file("catalog.xml");
$category = $catalog->Category;
$name = $category->Name;
$location = $category->Location;
$room = $location->Room;

for ($i = 0; $i <= 22; $i++)
{
$display = $catalog->xpath("//Category/Name[contains(text("CAT1"),'".$category[$i]->$name."']/parent::");
{
echo $display;
echo $room;
}
}
?>
```

---

The result is to display all details listed under Node [Category][Name] = CAT1, [Location][Room] but I got error in display

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/a3440614/public_html/arr0.php on line 11

---

Any help to correct and simplify it appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is this your actual code? Because it seems you forgot to escape your double quote in your XPath string, e.g. `text(\"CAT1\")`.

Comment: Hi passerby, I changed according to your advise but still encounter problem.  I believe is the way I code it.  Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath() [simplexmlelement.xpath]: xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed in /home/a3440614/public_html/arr0.php on line 10

Comment: Try to `vardump` your variables to debug, e.g. `$category`, the XPath string, etc..

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) { [0]=> string(7) " Alpha " } }   This is what I am getting but when I change to echo $display, it shows "Array"